# CSS: hide first-list item of ul with second depth

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following structure for a navigation …

```
<ul role="navigation">
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
        <a href="#">Sections</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-6">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Members</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Become Member</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Whatever</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I hide the first appearance of each `<a>` inside the outer list elements?
In my case I'm talking about `<a href="#">Sections</a>` and `<a href="#">About</a>`

I thought

```
ul li > a { display:none; }
```

or

```
ul > li > a { display:none; }
```

should be doing the trick, but it hides everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because all the `a`s are children of `li`s which are children of `ul`s.

Your top-level `ul` has a `role="navigation"` so you can select that:

```
ul[role="navigation"] > li > a { display:none; }
```

Comment: what is role attribute btw?

Comment: @defau1lt: It's an HTML5 attribute.

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar: That will select all of them too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and the most efficient way would be to add class like `.hidden {display: none;}`, but you could also add a class to the outer `ul`, and then:

`.ul-outer-class > li > a { display: none; }`

It's also more efficient than using attribute selectors.